# strip first 75 characters of string and maintain words

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to strip the first 75 characters from various strings (sentences / phrases) and it seems right but I need to ensure that the now words are truncated in the process. Meaning that if the 75 character is part of a word it needs to fall back to the beginning of the word or nearest space..

I thought of stripping the entire string into separate words and then counting the length of combining the words and stopping when I reach the target but what do I do in the case when it is not a valid sentence just a bunch of characters jammed together. I thought of using grammar parsing tool libraries and parsing into tokens etc but that seems to over complicated.

```
if text.length() > 75 then
    ctext = text.remove(text.length, 75) & "..."
endif
```

I put elipses at the end but using the above I also get the error:

does anyone have any better suggestions.

Comment: Your idea is pretty sound but I understand your concern, if somebody wrote 75 characters and no space, it wouldn't be truncated at all. Wouldn't it be better to truncate a bit more than possibly nothing at all? What about sentences less than 75 characters?

Comment: Skurmedel: Sentences less than 75 characters are irrelevant as the condition on the `If` is already false.

Comment: @Joey: Yes, you are right. I need more tea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply using Regex.Replace()?

```
Regex.Replace(myString, "^.{0,75} ", "")
```

This will match up to 75 characters at the start of the string and a space following it. Of course, you still need to account for strings that have 77 non-space characters at the start, but it gets you quite far already.

PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> $w = 'This is a quite long text. It might contain some words. Furthermore, it exceeds 75 characters of length and therefore must be truncated.'
PS Home:\> $w.substring(0,75)
This is a quite long text. It might contain some words. Furthermore, it exc
PS Home:\> $w -replace '^.{0,75} '
exceeds 75 characters of length and therefore must be truncated.
```

Comment: yeah let me try that and set the word conditiion

Comment: used dim reg as regex = new regex("^.{0,75}", regexoptions.ignorecase dim m as match = reg.match(...